# I can't get yahoo mail notifications

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, yahoo

I use Ubuntu 18.04,  Firefox browser and my email address is myname@yahoo.co.uk

I have enabled mail notifications both at Firefox settings and at yahoo mail page too, but with no avail. Nothing happens when I receive a mail.

Any help please ?

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: At this forum I see many questions about applications with Ubuntu OS. Why not one more ?